# XSLT 1.0: Optimize Matching/Logic Efficiency for adjusting Text Values in Very Large Documents

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am transforming medical record data that is stored in XML with XSLT 1.0.  Because these are patient records, while it is going to be okay to adjust certain text values, nothing can be removed, so I have to begin with the identity template.

I need to adjust the textual content of certain nodes based on a logical condition, such as another sibling node containing any one of up to 10 different ID numbers.  I have tried filtering with predicates, and, because of its mentioning in chapter 4 of the *XSLT Cookbook*, I have tried applying a `For-Each` with its supposedly faster ‘selecting’ method, rather than a ‘filtering’ approach based on `Choose-When` logic.  I’ve found the differences between Match with a predicate and using For-Each’s Select with a predicate to be negligible.  I am very open to using Keys but am not quite certain how to apply them to help with my problem.

I have two main problems:

1. For some facilities, I have to evaluate whether the sibling node contains any one of a large number of IDs, let’s say 10.  This makes predicates unwieldy and probably slow, as in [Item/number=‘123’ or Item/number=‘789’ or … + 10 or more other possibilities].
2. Some XML documents being processed are very large.  They can be up to 5MB, with one I’ve found at 15MB.  In this worst case scenario, just for the records of the type I’m evaluating within the larger document, there are over 9,000 nodes that must be either evaluated or filtered, and potentially adjusted.

It’s crucial I find the most efficient way to match on and adjust the text of nodes meeting the conditions.  We’re experiencing serious delays in processing and record retrieval times.  And if I can find an optimal solution, there will be multiple places I can re-write old XSLT templates and really improve things.

I have XML that’s something like this:

```
<Facilities>
    <Facility>XYZ</Facility>
    <Records>
        <!--  lots and lots of other kinds of records here A to Z, long XML before this.  -->
        <!--  RecordAAA #1  -->
        <RecordAAA>
            <Item>
                <number>123</number>
                <definition>123 really means this</definition>
            </Item>
            <ItemCategory>
                <ID>AAA</ID>
                <IdDescription>AAA</IdDescription>
            </ItemCategory>
        </RecordAAA>
        <!--  RecordAAA #2  -->
        <RecordAAA>
            <Item>
                <number>456</number>
                <definition>456 really means this</definition>
            </Item>
            <ItemCategory>
                <ID>AAA</ID>
                <IdDescription>AAA</IdDescription>
            </ItemCategory>
        </RecordAAA>
        <!--  RecordAAA #3  -->
        <RecordAAA>
            <Item>
                <number>123</number>
                <definition>123 really means this</definition>
            </Item>
            <ItemCategory>
                <ID>AAA</ID>
                <IdDescription>AAA</IdDescription>
            </ItemCategory>
        </RecordAAA>
        <!--  lots and lots of other kinds of records here A to Z, long XML after this.  -->    
    </Records>
</Facilities>
```

Desired Output:  `<ItemCategory> <ID>` and  `<ItemCategory> <IdDescription>` content changed based on RecordAAA #2’s Item/Number text being ‘456’, 
while RecordAAA #1 and #3 simply copied over:

```
<Facilities>
    <Facility>XYZ</Facility>
    <Records>
        <!--  lots and lots of other kinds of records here A to Z, long XML, before this.  -->
        <!--  RecordAAA #1  -->
        <RecordAAA>
            <Item>
                <number>123</number>
                <definition>123 really means this</definition>
            </Item>
            <ItemCategory>
                <ID>AAA</ID>
                <IdDescription>AAA</IdDescription>
            </ItemCategory>
        </RecordAAA>
        <!--  RecordAAA #2  -->
        <RecordAAA>
            <Item>
                <number>456</number>
                <definition>456 really means this</definition>
            </Item>
            <!--  ID and IdDescription have been changed.  -->
            <ItemCategory>
                <ID>BBB</ID>
                <IdDescription>BBB</IdDescription>
            </ItemCategory>
        </RecordAAA>
        <!--  RecordAAA #3  -->
        <RecordAAA>
            <Item>
                <number>123</number>
                <definition>123 really means this</definition>
            </Item>
            <ItemCategory>
                <ID>AAA</ID>
                <IdDescription>AAA</IdDescription>
            </ItemCategory>
        </RecordAAA>
        <!--  lots and lots of other kinds of records here A to Z, long XML, after this.  -->   
    </Records>
</Facilities>
```

I have XSLT templates like this, and of course this works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!--  Identity template  -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Records/RecordAAA[Item/number='456' or Item/number='789' or Item/number='101112']/ItemCategory">
        <ItemCategory>
            <ID>BBB</ID>
            <IdDescription>BBB</IdDescription>
        </ItemCategory>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But what should I do if I have facilities with more codes, and it begins to look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Records/RecordAAA[Item/number='456' 
                                                or Item/number='789' 
                                                or Item/number='101112'
                                                or Item/number='1314'
                                                or Item/number='1516'
                                                or Item/number='1718'
                                                or Item/number='1920'
                                                or Item/number='2122'
                                                or Item/number='2324'
                                                or Item/number='2526'
                                                or Item/number='2728']/ItemCategory">
    <ItemCategory>
        <ID>BBB</ID>
        <IdDescription>BBB</IdDescription>
    </ItemCategory>
</xsl:template>
```

This still creates the desired output (as would a long series of `Choose-When` conditions) but how can I get it done *faster?*  Is there a way to really make this more efficient?

If it matters for your answer, we are using the Xalan processor and I'm stuck with version 1.0.

Thank you very much for any solid insights.

Comment: Why are you stuck with Xalan and version 1.0? Why isn't it an option to move to something more modern?

Comment: Another observation: 5Mb is not "very large" these days. But size isn't really a factor here: your transformation time is going to be linear with document size whatever you do.

Comment: Fair enough.  Maybe upgrading is something we could look at.  It's just we have a ton of interdependencies in our enterprise system; we'd likely be afraid of inadvertently breaking something.  If we were to change, would that open up more efficient ways to do things?

Comment: If you moved to Saxon then you would benefit from ten years extra development work on optimization. Whether this has any impact on your particular stylesheet is something you would have to assess. Saxon-EE, for example, attempts to evaluate (a=1 or a=2 or a=17 or a=34...) using a hash table lookup.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I'll investigate what it would take for us.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can make these comparisons run any faster.

You can make your code cleaner by keeping a list of facilities in a parameter or separate file.

Here's an example XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name='facilityfile'>fax.xml</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name='facility' select='document($facilityfile)//facility/@nbr'/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--
<xsl:template match="Records/RecordAAA[Item/number='456' or Item/number='789' or Item/number='101112']/ItemCategory">
-->

<xsl:template match='ItemCategory'>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='preceding-sibling::Item/number=$facility'>
            <ItemCategory>
                <ID>BBB</ID>
                <IdDescription>BBB</IdDescription>
            </ItemCategory>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the facilities fax.xml content

```
<xml>
    <facility nbr='456'/>
    <facility nbr='567'/>
    <facility nbr='678'/>
    <facility nbr='789'/>
</xml>
```

Comment: I appreciate this response.  If I really can't get more efficient, I can certainly do something like this.  Still just wondering whether there is a better overall approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- generate-id(../..) returns the id of the grandparent of number.  ie.   RecordAAA -->
<xsl:key name="myKey" match="number[.='456' or .='789' or .='101112']" use="generate-id(../..)"/>

<!--  Identity template  -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- generate-id(..) returns the parent of ItemCategory.  ie.  RecordAAA-->
<xsl:template match="ItemCategory[key('myKey', generate-id(..))]">
  <ItemCategory>
    <ID>BBB</ID>
    <IdDescription>BBB</IdDescription>
  </ItemCategory>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I did this with Microsoft VS XSLT version 1.0.  If that key does not work for you in the template match, then use it in a xsl:choose within the template.  Let me know, if this  works for you.  Cheers!

Comment: Bluewood66, thank you for the work.  This answer looked very powerful to me and was along the lines and kind of thinking I was after.  I re-wrote some templates and tried some experiments, did some timing tests.  Sadly, I must report I couldn't see much difference.  This kind of indexing and use of keys is what I thought would have a big impact.  For now, I'm still stumped.

Comment: One thing you could try is running your code in a different XSLT processor.  It may just be the Xalan processor is not optimizing.  Otherwise, take a look at your hardware and network speeds.  If you are running over a VPN connection, you may not be getting enough resources.  From the size of the files you mentioned and the code you wrote, XSLT should process it in a blink.  XSLT should be very fast.  Anyway, good luck....

Comment: Bluewood66, thanks.  I'm still working with your ideas some.  Trying the concept in our actual system, I am having errors when trying to use the key in the template match.  You seemed to suggest I might run into this.  Do you know why this happens?

Comment: As I mentioned in my first note, if the key does not work in the template match, try it in a choose statement.  It looks like you already got this running back on 3/4.  Otherwise, I don't know why it won't work for you.  Probably something to do with  Xalan.